# Is it possible to get text style for each words individually?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides, textrange, textstyle

I know it is possible to get the text style of a selected word using
 `getSelection().getTextRange().getTextStyle()`

but if I want to retrieve text styles from a previous slide word by word (getting each word's text style individually), is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the [PageElements](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/page-element) of the slide, and retrieve the text style from each element.

For each `PageElement`, you would have to check whether its type has [TextRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range) as one of its properties (only [Shape](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape) and [TextCell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/table-cell) elements have `TextRange`). If you try to retrieve text from an element that does not contain text, you might end up getting an error.

Then, for each `textRange` that you retrieve, you can iterate through its runs (the different segments contained in this text that have a different text style), and retrieve the text style for each run.

#### Code sample:

```js
function getTextStyles() {
  var slideId = "your-slide-id"; ID of the slide you want to retrieve text style
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slide = presentation.getSlideById(slideId);
  var pageElements = slide.getPageElements(); // Get all page elements in slide
  pageElements.forEach(function(pageElement) { // Loop through all page elements in slide
    if (pageElement.getPageElementType() == "SHAPE") { // Check that current page element is of type "SHAPE"
      var textRange = pageElement.asShape().getText(); // Get text belonging to current page element
      textRange.getRuns().forEach(function(run) { // Loop through all runs in text
        var textStyle = run.getTextStyle(); // Get current row text style
        console.log(textStyle);
      });
    };
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- The code above logs the `TextStyle` of all the text belonging to `Shape` elements in the slide. `TableCell` elements can also contain text, so if you want to retrieve that information too, you would have to modify the script accordingly (take a look at [Class Table](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/table)).

#### Reference:

- [PageElements](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/page-element)
- [TextRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range)
- [Enum PageElementType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/page-element-type)

Comment: I didn't know about the getRuns() method... thanks a million!

Comment: @SafwatAliKhan You're welcome. If you consider this answer helpful, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This is useful because this community relies on it to share knowledge to other users.